# Isoperimetric inequality and mass

Tags: newtonian-gravity, surface-tension, fluid-statics

I'm wondering how to prove that if you take a small amount of mercury (just a drop), it ll form a sphere, but more you give it, more it looks like an ellipsoid? I have the intuition, but I don't know how to prove it?

Comment: You need to formulate the problem more rigorously. In the isoperimetric case, the shape minimises the area while keeping the volume constant. In this case the droplet is minimising area plus potential energy with a given volume and the constraint that it cannot pass through the table.

Comment: Okay but i dont know how to find the equation for then minimizing it. That s what i search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have an energy minimization problem with constraints. The total energy is equal to the surface energy plus potential energy.

The surface energy is $E_{surf}=\gamma \int_S dA$ where $\gamma$ is the surface energy density and the integral just represents the total surface area of the droplet.

The potential energy is $E_{pot}=\int_V \rho g z dV$ where $z$ is the height, $\rho$ is density and $g$ gravity; here we sum it up across the volume.

Then there is the constraint that the droplet needs to have $z>0$ since it is on top of a surface and volume $V=\int_V dV$ that is constant. Real liquids will also have a wetting constraint about the angle the top surface meets the surface it rests on. Now we need to "just" minimise $E_{surf}+E_{pot}$ given the constraints.

As you add more mercury to the droplet the volume constraint forces the surface and potential energy to go up. When the volume is small the surface energy term will dominate so the droplet will mainly minimise area and be spherical. As it gets larger the potential energy term will play a larger role, and now being flat starts to be favoured. In the limit the droplet will become a very wide, flat layer with a curved edge.

Solving this is of course somewhat tricky. As an applied maths guy, I would consider using some numerical software like [surface evolver](http://facstaff.susqu.edu/brakke/evolver/evolver.html) (they have the droplet on a surface as an [example](http://facstaff.susqu.edu/brakke/evolver/examples/examples.htm)). Way more elegant is to [solve it variationally](http://www.doiserbia.nb.rs/img/doi/1450-5584/2012/1450-55841201027L.pdf).

One obvious simplification is to assume the droplet is symmetric around the vertical axis: the droplet is some kind of surface of revolution. This allows rewriting the equations above in a simpler form ([this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00296537) then further assumes the surface shape can be approximated by a spline curve and solves it). If say the width of the droplet at height $z$ is $r(z)$ and that $r(0)=0$:
$$E=\int_0^{z_{max}} (2\pi \gamma) r(z) \sqrt{1+r'^2(z)} + (\pi \rho g) z r^2(z) dz$$
This can be minimized by turning it into a differential equation using the [Euler-Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)  and then finding the solution of the equation that obeys the constraints, but there I typically get stuck in the algebra.

Comment: it is truly interesting and rich thank you very much :)